# Adding fees for paypal and credit card depends on customer geo zone

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I have found this - [WooCommerce: Add fees to card based on payment gateway selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405229/woocommerce-add-fees-to-card-based-on-payment-gateway-selected/25833112?noredirect=1#comment40416672_25833112) nice plugin, but I would need a plugin that I can set up three different fees to customers from different geo zones..

For example. - Slovenia - 4.8% - Serbia - 4.9% ect..

How can I do that? With which plugin?
Or is it possible to modify upper plugin to add geo zones for each fee? I am not good at coding, so I do appreciate some help.

---

@Marin Atanasov -  I can't, because this is not tax, it's fee and it's not acceptable for our inspection. I already had that tax created in paypal, but it's not ok, because I have three different webstores, one in OC, one in woocommerce, and one in shopmania. I found one extension for OC that already calculates my fee for slovenian users, so I removed tax (so called fee) for them in paypal, but than the webshop in shopmania targets costumers in ex yugoslavia. But, the OC shop also does not exclude ex yugoslavian costumers, so the fee can be charged twice. The problem is also with the third webshop - woocommerce- where I have now for all costumers set up 3.4% fee, but if the costumer from ex yugoslavia orders than the fee is again charged twice, because I didn't remove it from tax in paypal. I need to find a resolution so the all three webshops have their own extension to calculate the fee, and delete taxes that I already set up in paypal.

If paypal would allow multiple webstores under 1 company name, this would be easy to fix.. but I can not enter my credit card number for all three webstores.. :(

Do you have any idea what to do? I am lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the built-in taxes? They provide you with the option to specify custom tax rates for countries.

To do this, you would have to:

- Create your custom tax rates for the preferred tax class under WooCommerce -> Settings -> Tax
- Select your preferred tax class for each of the products, and make each product Taxable
- Make sure the taxes are enabled and properly configured per your preferences in WooCommerce -> Settings -> Tax

Comment: please see comment above, I have too much words for this small comment box :D

Comment: I've read your comment. It appears that this requires a more complex solution, so i guess if you don't find a suitable plugin, you will need some custom coding, which is more complex than time-taking than expected for a question in Stack Overflow. In this case i recommend you seek the help of a professional WooCommerce developer to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use one plugin to add commission to certain payment gateways with different percentages

> Payment Gateway Based Fees and Discounts for WooCommerce

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32509873)